# Matching registry keys

Tags: c#, com, registry, registrykey, app-id

I have an application that seems to have the same registry key (COM Id) as another related application. I tried to change the app ID in c# but that does not work as the second application will not work if the first application is installed. If I uninstall one and unregistered it, the other application works. How do I change the com ID or registry key so they have unique IDs in the registry?

Comment: Which specific COM ID values are you identifying as having been duplicated? Could you post a snip of the parts of the registry where you see these duplicated ID value(s)?

Comment: @David W, This is a .net application that is being called from a COM application. I registered it with regasm. I don't see where the value is being duplicated in the registry, I can search more, but both applications started off the same before splitting so my thought that the com ID are the same in the registry. Since unregistering one and the other works.

Comment: Hmm, if you aren't actually seeing the registry duplication, then perhaps a more detailed description of your error situation is needed. I thought you actually were seeing duplicate ID's for unrelated COM objects. Are you saying the consuming COM application and your app have the same ID's?

Comment: The application does not start up. It just shows an error in windows. "could not load application." . I have two similar projects in c # that started as the same before being separated. The consuming COM application cannot consume the second application because it was registered second.

Comment: Which application, your new .NET app or the COM consuming app? What do you mean by "they started the same before splitting?" Splitting what? I am suspecting you may have to post quite a bit more detail on this to properly analyze your problem.

Comment: The consuming Com application makes calls to load the .net projects. The consuming COM is able to load the first registered .net application, but it fails to load the second .NET application. The two .net applications were one project and application previously, before different teams created different branches to build different products hence we have two different products but a lot of similar code. Hope this helps. I'm glad to provide more details.

Comment: Okay -I think that helps. If you now have distinct assemblies because an original .NET app has been "split" for some reason, those .NET apps are now separate assemblies and they're almost certainly going to require separate registrations. They won't be able to share the same AppID, because they're no longer the same app.

Comment: Yes, I do register them separately but it seems they share some id that I can't tell what it it. I changed the appid for the "second" application, but didn't help.

Comment: Do the .NET apps have their own, independent interfaces, or do they exist solely as what amounts to out-of-process COM servers?

Comment: Yes, they have independent interfaces

Comment: Without knowing more details, given these apps used to be "unified", I think you have a *dependency problem*. "App 1" registers and works, but things fail when "App 2" is registered. I am suspecting that "App 2" has a dependency on an object served by "App 1," but the registration of App 1 doesn't properly point to "App 2" as its object server. When "App2" is unregistered, "App 1" starts working on its own. That's a fairly sketchy outline, but it's where I'd start looking.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will troubleshoot with this in mind. I'm guessing simple changing the com clsid and appid won't work.

Comment: Well, that's why the dependency issue came to mind. Another scenario could be that App2 has a dependency on something it *used* to create (when unified), but is now created by App1. The way these app servers were split up is something to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be changing COM CLSID and APPID values. The ID's associated with applications and classes are integral to the COM registration mechanism for identifying and instantiating objects, so arbitrarily changing them will almost certainly break some aspect of the application.

The behavior your describing suggests something more fundamental at hand..

Comment: @ David W, Can you please explain why I can't change them for an application that I'm building and creating the installer for? Can't I change it to whatever I like? Thanks.